# My pet rat bit his cage mate, what do I do?

Tags: behavior, rat, exotic-pets, rodents

Recently I got two rats from a lady who could no longer care for them. She had them for a week and I've now had them for two weeks.

Today the youngest (2 months according to past owner) was climbing the bars and I saw what looks like a bite on his stomach. I was thinking it was caused by the oldest (5 months) as I've seen him nipping at the other. They're both males and have plenty of hammocks but always sleep together and love on each other. They do wrestle a bit but it's usually just play.

Any tips?

Comment: So how does this situation develop? Any new bite marks?

Answer (score 1):

I don't own any rats but I have friends who do and have done research as I want some. Have you had the rats neutered? This may stop them from quarrelling, and nipping each other.If this is the case it's all about dominance, they will fight each other to see whos stronger and who should be the important one. 
If you are worried about the bite or t looks infected take the rat to the vet.

hope this helps xx